# RAML API Designer Mock Service: HATEOAS response with absolute URLs?

Tags: json, rest, hateoas, hypermedia, raml

I created REST API mock using RAML tool. How can I return in my JSON object response hypermedia links with absolute paths?
Is there a way to include **baseUri** into my sample JSON object in order to create absolute path?

Right now I have relative path `"/users/ff33c2a1-b877-4415-9e62-115b8239c787"` in my JSON object:

```
{
"name": "John Smith",
"email": "john.smith@sample.com",
"status": "pending",
"_links": [
  {
    "rel": "self",
    "href": "/users/ff33c2a1-b877-4415-9e62-115b8239c787"
  }
]}
```

And actually I wanna have absolute path where root is taken from my **baseUri** value.

E.g. path should be something like `"http://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/a2683439-a5dc-409c-801a-c771042970fb/mocks/31e46658-b4ce-4f40-cc91-c4fd50f7a2d8/v1/users/ff33c2a1-b877-4415-9e62-115b8239c787"`

I tried using something like:

`"href": "{baseUri}/users/ff33c2a1-b877-4415-9e62-115b8239c787"`

or without quotes

`"href": {baseUri}/users/ff33c2a1-b877-4415-9e62-115b8239c787`

but none of the above worked.

I am using *RAML 0.8*.